# This site can’t be reached in IIS Windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a simple site using ASP.NET. I have deployet it using IIS Manager in windows 7, Here it's binding config :
[image]

When I open hisoka.poipo.com using my laptop, I got this error message :
[image]
Weell... I have been reading some articles about this error, most of them said that I have to allow port 80 in my firewall and I have set port 80 to be always opened, but the error is still showing up.
I have tried

```
hisoka.poipo.com/page.aspx
```

But the site still can't be reached. What I have missed here...??? Please help...
Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: Make sure that the dns record on the domain is pointing to the right external ip.

Comment: Yaaps..I'm working on it... :)
Thanks for your comment.. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you register hisoka.poipo.com in your local hosts file?

Usually here:
%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Open hosts file with any text editor `as administrator` and then add:

169.254.224.121         hisoka.poipo.com

[image]

Comment: After adding 169.254.224.221 hisoka.poipo.com to my hosts file. I got this error Mr. Sven Sowa :

HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.

Comment: Do you run the website with Windows Integrated Authentication? Maybe the IIS internal user doesnt have access to that directory where you have the website. Try adding the local group "IIS_IUSRS" to the filesystem where you have the website project. Normally read access should be good enough unless you write a logfile or open files in write mode from your website.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add your default page so if your aspx or asp page is named something obscure you will have to add the name in the default pages[Add Default Document to IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfrnF.png)